# Can't understand behaviour of MAPmethod?

Tags: jquery

```
var $inventory=$('#inventory tbody');
var quantities=$inventory.find('td:nth-child(2)')   // suppose it contains values of 2,3,4 inside td tags 
                  .map(function(index,qty){
                       return$(qty).text();
     }).get();
```

Now, i  dont get `map`  here. it'is used as `map(function(**index,qty**)` but according to [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

this should be like

```
  jQuery.map( arrayOrObject, callback**( value, indexOrKey** ) )
```

But the map mentioned in my code is still working great   but in a opposite way for INDEX and VALUE . 
and var `quantities` outputs
    `["2", "3", "4"]` 
  So, i am confused  ?   Seems like a documentation mistake !!

**[Edit:]** 
Above get() is used at the end but even if i dont use it ,the output is still the same i.e ["2", "3", "4"] So why to use it ? 
Say my modified code is now
 
`// .....same above code

                           return$(qty).text();
         });`

Comment: Why a minus 1 ?  this is ridiculous and misuse of priveleges :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two "map" methods: [one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) in the global object (`jQuery.map`) and [one](http://api.jquery.com/map/) that belongs to the result of a selection (`jQuery.fn.map`). The first one is intended to be used with regular JavaScript arrays or objects. You're using the second one, that applies to the list of elements selected (so, no need for that first argument).

Comment: Above  get() is used at the end but even if i dont use it ,the output is still the same  i.e ["2", "3", "4"]
So why to use it ?

Comment: Calling [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) without arguments just make a copy of your element set. If you want a specific one (ex. the third) you can use `$inventory.get(2)`. In this case it makes no difference, but if you plan to modify the set destructively, making a copy of it all might be useful.

Comment: you don't get it . WHat u said ,i understand  but i am saying ,why to use get() at first place when my variable quantities will still have the same output even if i don't use get () above !!

Comment: as I said, in this particular case it makes no difference! I have no idea why that code's author used it... you're safe to omit the get() if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

[**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

this is from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/) you are using `.map` that return the jquery object and inside the callback `this` refers to the current DOM elem

> .map( callback(index, domElement) )
>
> callback(index, domElement)A function object that will be invoked for
>   each element in the current set.

---

where as the link you have mentioned refers to `$.map` that returns the array

[**jQuery.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

> jQuery.map( array, callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray) )
>
> arrayThe Array to translate.
>
> callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray)The function to process each
>   item against. The first argument to the function is the array item,
>   the second argument is the index in array The function can return any
>   value. Within the function, this refers to the global (window) object.